# Only some PHP being outputted

Tags: templates, php, parse-order

I have the following php code in a template and it's not parsing the whole thing.  Any idea what the issue is?

Here's the php code:

```
<?php
include "Eventbrite.php"; 

$authentication_tokens = array('app_key'  => 'YOUR_APP_KEY',
                           'user_key' => 'YOUR_USER_KEY');

$eb_client = new Eventbrite( $authentication_tokens );

$events = $eb_client->user_list_events(); 
?>
```

Here's what's being outputted on frontend:

*'YOUR_APP_KEY', 'user_key'=>'YOUR_USER_KEY'); $eb_client = new Eventbrite( $authentication_tokens ); $events = $eb_client->user_list_events(); ?>*

Answer (score 1):

First thing, do you have php e[nabled on the template](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/edit_template.html#preferences)? It looks like it is thinking that:

```
<?php
include "Eventbrite.php"; 

$authentication_tokens = array('app_key'  =>
```

Is just a bad html element. So make sure to enable php on (I think you want) input.

Second, make sure that Eventbrite.php is actually being included correctly.